# Employer ending contract before notice period

Tags: salary, notice-period

I am about two weeks into my notice period, and my employer said he would prefer it if I finish off today.  All the work I was supposed to do has been handed in, including extra work.

I am afraid that they don't want to pay me for the full notice period.  Is there a standard document that I can get them to sign, to cover me in this kind of situation?  I am aware that, by law, they need to pay me for the full notice period.

Comment: I see from your profile that you are apparently located in South Africa. If that's the case, it might be useful to add this to the question and its title as practices might differ from one country to the other.

Comment: Do you have paid vacation; and if so, is any of that left over? I would guess that you have vacation days left that you wanted to spend around christmas...

Comment: If your boss says you can go, you can go. I had the same situation where my boss said 3 weeks before my actual finish date: 'Go home and spend your time looking for a new job'. However, I was still officially employed and they paid my salary till the end because they were required to by law. Your situation is similar, so that makes it a legal question which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: This is perhaps something you need to discuss with your Boss.  It may or may not be part of the contract.

Comment: As Jan said, it's common and normally you'd get paid until the end of your notice period. Of course you may have to use vacation time to cover those days. Ask your boss, he'll know. Or human resources...

Comment: Are you 2 weeks into the contract, or 2 weeks from finishing the contract? Your question isn't very clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would clarify with your boss whether "finishing up today" means that they will or won't pay you for the entire notice period.

Whilst it is always good to have legal recourse there are a couple of things that I think you should bear in mind.
1. Reputation - this is a company that you will likely need a reference from for your next job - if you take legal action then you can be almost guaranteed that they will ensure any potential employer is aware of that and it will put a lot of people off.
2. Do you have another job to go to? If not then you may want to ensure you are properly paid out to ensure you have whatever money you can while you look for a new job.

Ask your boss first, if they are trying to get out of paying you, then get some legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first of all you are a permanent employee, and you signed a contract of employment when you joined the company, I would use the contract as the first place to look for whether they need to pay you or not. If the contract doesn't specifically mention that they do not pay you for notice period, then you will very likely be able to ask them for the money owed to you for the full notice period, as well as any holiday you are owed. 
If you do have a contract which suggests they need to pay you your notice, contact HR and explain to them the situation. They may not know that the company is trying to avoid paying you your notice. Be reasonable with them, and give them enough time to investigate your claim. If, after this time you are still not receiving what you believe is due, you will need to seek legal advice.